# Can a set of bijections $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be equipollent to $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> Can a set of bijections $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be equipollent to $\Bbb{R}^n$? If it does, what is the value of $n$?

It could seem like a stupid question, but... I was thinking of a specific set's equipollence to $\Bbb{R}$. Using Galilei and Cantor's method, almost all of the sets I have found could be judged its equipollence.

Then, I thought about the set $\Bbb{F}: \{ f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} | \text{bijective} \}$. First, I thought about the equipollence to $\Bbb{R}$, but couldn't find the method. So, I thought about the equipollent to $\Bbb{R^2}$ and again failed...

Is it possible to find equipollent sets of $\Bbb{F}$?

Comment: The question is currently quite unclear, partially because you probably misunderstood how the word "correspond" should be used in a sentence.

Comment: @Trebor Alright, I did some research and edited my question. Is it clear now? (Sorry for my bad English...)

Comment: It is utterly unclear what you are asking.  Since you tag it with `order-theory`, what (partial/total) order are you putting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: I don't think "similar" is what you meant... Do you mean "equipollent"?

Comment: Is "similarity" supposed to be "bijectable"/"equipollent"/"has the same cardinality as"? Note that "uncountably infinite" is not a single cardinality; it just says "infinite and not countable". There are infinitely many cardinals that are different from each other and also uncountably infinite. No single cardinal is called "uncountably infinite" And "uncountably infinite" is **very different** from countably infinite, so I don't know why you write "(un)countable infinite".

Comment: @Trebor Oh, that's what I was to say... Thanks, I'll edit it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, I understood... My bad English makes people confused lol